# How to activate Conda env from Jupyter Notebook in Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have written a Python program and whenever I double click over it, it opens in Jupyter notebook but the thing is that it always opens with **base** env. I want this to open in a different Conda environment.

Let's say the name of my Conda environment is `ODAC`. **Can I add a command at start of my program so that it activates this Conda environment first and then executes the code?**

Comment: How are your creating the virtual environment?  Conda, virtualenv, etc?

Comment: what is extension of you file you launch?

Comment: Hello @James , yes i am creating using conda exactly.

Comment: Hello @404pio, The extension of file is .ipynb

Comment: It means first i need to change extension of my file and then use command to activate the virtual environment. Let's suppose, I changed the extension. How can i activate the environment now. Thank you :-)

Comment: Have you google "how to activate virtual env in windows" ?

Comment: Of course, I know activate ENV_NAME but it is not working.

Comment: **Important Prerequisite:** Are your envs configured to be used by Jupyter? If Jupyter is part of a Conda env, then this means having `conda_nb_kernels` installed in that env (not necessarily the one you want to use - just the one with Jupyter) and having `ipykernel` installed in the env you want to use. If Jupyter is installed separately then the env needs `ipykernel` installed, and you need to register the env via `python -m ipykernel install --user`.  Without this, the env can't be used in Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks @merv. Jupyter is installed separetly and ipykernel should work. Trying to set ipykernel.